# android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException and java.net.socketexception too many open files

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am getting android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException in a background process. I have ensured that I close cursors after I open them in all cases. I have even kept a static global counter which counts num of cursors opened just to ensure I am not leaking cursors.

Also, I am catching "java.net.socketexception too many open files" around the same time as CursorWindowAllocation exception.
I have looked at the number of open socket connections of my device using adb and it never goes beyond 200.

I am calling both network operations and DB operation in my service which runs periodically every 5 secs.
What could be a possible reason for these errors?

Comment: Can you provide the code of that service? But it really seems you are not closing things right.

Comment: I have observed that I have around 50 connections in TIME_WAIT state, maybe because I am running the background service with 5 network connections every 5 secs. I have reduced this frequency to once every minute.
I'll update here if this works out